# Problems Compiling with SDL2 in C

Tags: c, gcc, linker, sdl, sdl-2

Ive been trying to compile a simple program in order to test SDL2 but for some reason when I try to do it the compiler says that the SDL_Window is an unkown type.  I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what im doing wrong.(My operating system is Ubuntu linux) Here is the full output:

```
thin.c: In function ‘main’:
thin.c:9:5: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_Window’
     SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer
     ^
thin.c:14:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SDL_CreateWindow’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     window = SDL_CreateWindow(
     ^
thin.c:16:9: error: ‘SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
         ^
thin.c:16:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
thin.c:20:9: error: ‘SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
         ^
thin.c:35:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SDL_DestroyWindow’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
```

Here is also the source code. Its from the API documentation:

```
// Example program:
// Using SDL2 to create an application window

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

    // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );

    // Check that the window was successfully created
    if (window == NULL) {
        // In the case that the window could not be made...
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // The window is open: could enter program loop here (see SDL_PollEvent())

    SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example

    // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

finally here is the command i issued to compile the code:

```
gcc thin.c -o test -Wall -lSDL2
```

Thank you

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, don't write comments to things that are obvious. "Declare a pointer"? Yes we can actually *see* that. Instead save comments for things that are *not* obvious, or for telling *why* you do something and not something else.

Comment: As for your problem, do you get an error message about it not finding the `SDL/SDL.h` header file?

Comment: It seems to have no problem finding the actual header file.

Comment: BTW i didn't actually write the code. This was an example from the SDL2 API documentation that I used for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SDL/SDL.h` is SDL 1.2 or before. SDL2 header is `SDL2/SDL.h`.

This reflects error messages - SDL 1.2 didn't have `SDL_Window` type, or many other things.

Probably more portable way is including just `SDL.h` and manually feeding include path to compiler (with `-I` flag, in case of gcc), or using `sdl2-config --cflags`.

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

It seems the path to the includes is not right.
Make sure you use the -I switch and set the path to the SDL2 includes